# Reversible and irreversible cyclic processes

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

The answer in Arihant's book is given as (b), but wouldn't (c) be correct as well? This is a question of IIT JAM Chemistry.

> A system undergoes two cyclic processes 1 and 2. Process 1 is reversible and Process 2 is irreversible. The correct statement relating to the two processes is
>   (a) $\delta S=0$ for Process 1, while $\Delta S\neq0$ for Process 2
>   (b) $Q_\text{cyclic}=0$ for Process 1 and $Q_\text{cyclic}\neq0$ for Process 2
>   (c) More heat can be converted to work in Process 1 than in Process 2
>   (d) More work can be converted to heat in Process 1 than in Process 2

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 3):

**Answer b is incorrect** for the reversible Carnot cycle.  The book has given the wrong answer. Answer c is correct if only one cycle of each process is carried out.  You can obviously convert more heat to work if you run process 2 through the same cycle several times, which also counts as a cyclic process.

Comment: Well Sir, it's given that from Clausius inequality, for reversible process, q(cycle)=0 and for irreversible process , q(cycle) less than 0 . I agree with you on the latter.

Comment: That is NOT what the Clausius inequality says.  Are you saying that you think that Qcyclic is zero for the reversible Carnot cycle.

Comment: So, what do you think?  Do you still stand by what you said about the Clausius inequality indicating that, for a reversible process q(cycle) = 0?

Comment: Yes sir, actually this answer given in the book got me a bit confused. I understood that q(cyclic) is not 0 for a reversible cyclic process. But, would q(cyclic) for an irreversible process be less than q(cyclic) for reversible process?

Comment: Depending on the reversible path selected, it could be less or it could be more. But, the change in entropy for any reversible cyclic path is zero.   Please understand that I am asserting that, **contrary to what your book says, answer b is incorrect.**

Comment: Also, of course, the change in entropy for any irreversible cyclic path is also zero.

Comment: Yes sir I understand that answer b is incorrect. But sir, (with reference to your last comment that ∆S for any irreversible cyclic change is also zero), doesn't the Clausius inequality say that it's less than zero?

Comment: No.  Entropy is a function of state.  So, in a cyclic process, where the final state of the system is the same as the initial state of the system, the change in entropy is zero for both reversible and irreversible processes.  The Clausius inequality says that the change in entropy for the combination of system and surroundings is greater or equal to zero.  So, for an irreversible cyclic process, all the entropy generated in the process is transferred to the surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

A is correct because
B can't b correct as heat is a path dependent process.
Nothing can be commented over C and D because we are not sure about the type of thermodynamic process mention in the question.
Here A can be inferred for sure as entropy for cyclic reversible process is constant.